# Convert view into view that extends view

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a possibility that in the xml resource layout to have a base view and when inflate it to convert it to a specific view ?

For example having a custom view called MyCustomView that extends EditText, and some views that extends MyCustomView like MyCustomViewNumber or MyCustomViewPassword and a layout like this :

```
<com.example.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .....>
</com.example.MyCustomView>
```

Is it possible that after I inflate this xml, MyCustomView to became one of MyCustomViewNumber or MyCustomViewPassword (inherit all attributes from those two). MyCustomViewNumber will be an EditText(better said a MyCustomView) that in the constructor method has setInputType to number.

```
View baseView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.id.my_layout, container, false);
baseView = new MyCustomViewNumber(getContext()). //with this line I want that my view from the layout to take all attributes from MyCustomViewNumber.
```

Recapitulating:

`public class MyCustomView extends EditText`

`public class MyCustomViewNumber extends MyCustomView { 
      ctors > this.setInputType("number"); 
}`

`public class MyCustomViewPassword extends MyCustomView{ ctors > same as above }`

Inflate MyCustomView. Set the inflated view to MyCustomViewNumber or MyCustomViewPassword. Is it possible ?

**Basically I do this because I need the "layoutParams". I know that I could get the layout params from the inflated view, remove it and then add the new one with that parameters.**

Comment: I don't think so. You can't cast Base class to extended class. Only reverse is possible. This would be killing inheritance concept.

Comment: You're right. But I don't really want that. What I want is to take the attributeSet from the extended class and give them to base class.

Comment: That's kind of same, isn't it? A object of base class can't get attributes of its extended class like this. I feel you should find another way to achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: The view class you declare in XML has to be inflated by the system so it has to know the name of an exact class, not an interface or abstract class. So it's not possible. The other way around is of course.

Answer (score 1):

No, the class whose fully qualified name you use in your XML is instantiated by the system, and thus must be a concrete class.

Comment: Instead, create the two separate classes, and try to extract the shared behaviour that would have been in CustomView (your intended base class) to another class that can be used by each of the actual custom views.